# How do you write a java compare editor using CompareEditorInput to compare 2 strings

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have been trying to get this to work for days now and I just cant get my head around it...

I am using java swt and am trying to open a tab which will compare 2 strings and show the differences highlighted side by side. I have seen a number of examples but cant seem to find the code to implement.

I have read https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_compare_editor%3F but unsure how to actually implement this.

Whenever I try, I get an error -

Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:

The tutorial says to use -

```
public class CompareEditorAction implements 
IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate {
  public void run(IAction action) {
     CompareUI.openCompareEditor(new MyCompareInput());
  }
}
```

But I am not sure how to actually invoke it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Code where error is being thrown -

```
CompareEditorInput cei = new CompareEditorInput(new CompareConfiguration()) {

    @Override
    protected Object prepareInput(IProgressMonitor arg0)
            throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        CompareItem ancestor = new CompareItem("Common", "contents");
        CompareItem left = new CompareItem("Left", "new contents");
        CompareItem right = new CompareItem("Right", "old contents");

        getCompareConfiguration().setLeftLabel(left.getName());
        getCompareConfiguration().setRightLabel(right.getName());
        getCompareConfiguration().setAncestorLabel(ancestor.getName());

        return new DiffNode(null,Differencer.CONFLICTING,ancestor,left,right);
    }
};
```

CompareItem class

```
package kam.test;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI;

import org.eclipse.compare.CompareConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput;
import org.eclipse.compare.IModificationDate;
import org.eclipse.compare.IStreamContentAccessor;
import org.eclipse.compare.ITypedElement;
import org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.Differencer;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;


class CompareItem implements IStreamContentAccessor, ITypedElement, IModificationDate {

private String contents, name;

CompareItem(String name, String contents) {
    this.name = name;
    this.contents = contents;
}

@Override
public long getModificationDate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getType() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ITypedElement.TEXT_TYPE;
}

@Override
public InputStream getContents() throws CoreException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(contents.getBytes());
}

@Override
public org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image getImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Stack trace -

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.compare.internal.ICompareUIConstants.(ICompareUIConstants.java:15)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.(CompareEditorInput.java:163)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:203)
    at kam.test.NewCompareTest.main(NewCompareTest.java:76)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeManager.getInstance(ContentTypeManager.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getContentTypeManager(InternalPlatform.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getContentTypeManager(Platform.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareUIPlugin.(CompareUIPlugin.java:213)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
    ... 8 more

Comment: Can you please post the full stacktrace, and some extra code of yours?

Comment: The compare editor can only be used in an Eclipse plugin, it won't work in a plain Java program.

Comment: Thanks for the info, appreciated. Will save me wasting more time trying to implement something thats not possible :-D

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/swtcompare/ suggests it can be done